# Angular 2+ CRUD Operations With Firebase 5.0

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, angular2-services, angularfire5

I have realized that firebase 5.0 operations are different from the previous verions https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md. Kindly help me with an angular Service that basically perform CRUD on firebase Realtime Database using this interface

```
//Person.ts
interface Person{
    $id :string;
    name: string;
    age: string;
    gender: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`

```
//providers/person.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';
import {Person} from './Person.ts';

@Injectable()
export class PersonProvider {

  private personListRef = this.db.list<Person>('persons');

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  /**
   * Creates Person
   */
  createPerson(person: Person) {
    return this.personListRef.push(person);
  }

  /**
   * Reads Persons
   */
  getPersons() {
    return this.personListRef;
  }

  /**
   * Updates Person
   */
  updatePerson(person: Person) {
    return this.personListRef.update(person.key, person);
  }

  /**
   * Deletes Person
   */
  deletePerson(person: Person) {
    return this.personListRef.remove(person.key);
  }
}
```

`

Depending on the version of AngularFire2 you are using (tested with 5.0.0-rc.11), you may need to install rxjs@6.

```
npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save
```